# Swift Firebase UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to create a "Share" button for my post's so a user can share it where ever using the UIActivityViewController. My posts are created within a tableview controller where the cell has its own view controller as well. Not sure if I should be doing this within the cell's viewcontroller or the way I am currently trying. Here is my whole viewcontroller that loads the posts to the tableview. So, I need help accessing the data within each cell, not sure how to do so. When I was creating a geofence message, I was able to access each message by doing a firebase call and comparing it to the identifier I assigned to it. I am trying to use the same logic for my "ShareAction".

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SDWebImage
import IGListKit
import SwiftyJSON
import CoreLocation

class CustomerPostsView: UITableViewController,  CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var feedTableView: UITableView!
var feeds = [Post]()

let loggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    // get posts for all users
    getAllPosts(refreshing: false, refreshControl: nil)

    // refresh control
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshControlAction(refreshControl:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    self.feedTableView.insertSubview(refreshControl, at: 0)

}

@objc func refreshControlAction(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    getAllPosts(refreshing: true, refreshControl: refreshControl)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func optionsButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    let editAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in

    })

    let shareAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Share", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in
        Database.database().reference().child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "download_url").queryEqual(toValue: self.feeds).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.exists() {

            } else {
                print(snapshot)
            }
        })

    })

    let deletepostAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in

    })


    alertController.addAction(editAction)
    alertController.addAction(shareAction)
    alertController.addAction(deletepostAction)
    alertController.addAction(deleteAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


// MARK: Table View Methods
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.feeds.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomerPostsViewCell {
        let post = self.feeds[indexPath.row]
        let caption = post.caption
        let downloadURL = post.downloadURL
        let name = post.name
        let address = post.address
        let state = post.state
        let date = post.date
        let distance = post.distance

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

        // Business Name
        cell.businessNameLabel.text = name
        cell.businessAddressLabel.text = address
        cell.businessStateLabel.text = state
        cell.businessPostDistanceLabel.text = distance

        // caption
        cell.captionView.text = caption

        // post image
        cell.businessPostImage.image = nil
        if let postURL = URL(string: downloadURL) {
            let postRequest = URLRequest(url: postURL)
            cell.businessPostImage.setImageWith(postURL, placeholderImage: nil, options: SDWebImageOptions.progressiveDownload, completed: { (imageRequest, imageResponse, error) -> Void in
                // failure downloading image
                print("Error downloading Firebase post image")
                print(error)
            })
        }

        // set date of post
        cell.postTimeLabel.text = dateString


        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}


// MARK: Queries
func getAllPosts(refreshing: Bool, refreshControl: UIRefreshControl?) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "businessName").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    //observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            self.feeds = []
            for item in dict {
                let json = JSON(item.value)
                let uid = json["uid"].stringValue
                var name: String = json["businessName"].stringValue
                let address: String = json["businessStreet"].stringValue
                let state: String = json["businessCity"].stringValue
                let caption: String = json["caption"].stringValue
                let downloadURL: String = json["download_url"].stringValue
                let timestamp = json["timestamp"].doubleValue
                let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp/1000)

                let lat = json["businessLatitude"].doubleValue
                let long = json["businessLongitude"].doubleValue
                let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

                let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                let distanceInMeters: Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                let distanceInMiles: Double = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137
                let distanceLabelText = String(format: "%.2f miles away", distanceInMiles)


                let usersReference = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users").queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: uid)
                usersReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                        let userInfo = dict.allValues[0]
                        let userJSON = JSON(userInfo)
                        name = userJSON["name"].stringValue

                    }
                    let post = Post(uid: uid, caption: caption, downloadURL: downloadURL, name: name, date: date, address: address, state: state, distance: distanceLabelText)


                    self.feeds.append(post)

                    // sort posts by date/distance
                    //self.feeds.sort {$0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedAscending}
                    self.feeds.sort {$0.distance.compare($1.distance) == .orderedAscending}
                    self.feedTableView.reloadData()

                })
            }
        }
        if refreshing {
            refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        }
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
    })
}

}
```

**Below is my Firebase Call Geofence logic I am trying to use for sharing a post, to get that specific posts data**

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
    Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").queryOrdered(byChild: "businessName").queryEqual(toValue: region.identifier).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
                self.name = dictionary["businessName"] as? String
                self.message = dictionary["geofenceMessage"] as? String
            }
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: self.name, message: self.message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Snapshot does not exist")
        }
    })
    print(state)
    print("region :\(region.identifier)")
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the error you are having? Is it just not working? Is something `null`?

Comment: I just keep getting the Thread 1 error. I am unsure how to "tag" each post with a String so I can just call it in the Firebase Query. Right now I am trying to work on SDWebImage and pulling the image from the Cache but no luck, not even sure if it would work. Im sure if there was a way to set it like the "region.identifer" it would be a lot easier.

Comment: What is Thread 1 doing? Are you able to break point and step through to find the line?

Comment: I just keep on getting "Thread 1: signal SIGBRT" "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" ... I am pretty sure it's because I am trying to run a query against all of my posts instead of basically saying which specific one

Comment: I am able to have access to all posts and their data but the problem is getting which specific one I want to share